# Laravel Horizon - Multiple queues from same supervisor with different processes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

When trying to use Laravel Horizon instead of Laravel Forge's queue setup, I have an issue with "translating" two workers into the horizon `config.php` file.

Let's say we have two queues: "queue1" and "queue2" but one queue shall have different processes and a different timeout, how can I achieve this with only one supervisor?

The current setup is:

```
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['queue1'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 20,
            'tries' => 3,
            'timeout' => 30,
        ],
        'supervisor-2' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['queue2'],
            'balance' => 'simple',
            'processes' => 5, // different
            'tries' => 1, // different
            'timeout' => 60, // different
        ],
    ],
```

But I do not want to have 2 supervisors but only 1. How can this be achieved whilst maintaining different tries, processes and timeouts?

Comment: What speaks against having two supervisors? You can't do what you want with one supervisor. `processes` for example is a config that does only make sense with a supervisor because depending on the `balance` setting, it will assign busy queues more workers. It does so only in scope of itself, i.e. it won't take processes from other supervisors.

Comment: @Namoshek fair enough... Thanks!